# Relation between angles in a 3D space

Tags: euclidean-geometry, vectors

We have two vectors, $u$ and $v$, both of length 1. Let $\alpha$ denote the angle between them. We also have vector $w$ (perpendicular both to $u$ and $v$) and two other vectors, that are connecting heads of the $u$ and $v$ with head of $w$. The angle between them is denoted with $\beta$.

How do we calculate $\beta$ and express it in terms of $\alpha$.

This is trivial, if $w=o$ (then $\beta=\alpha$), but for any other $w$ this angle is smaller and smaller for longer $w$. I want to prove this last statement.

What I got so far:

$\alpha = arccos( {u.v \over |u||v|} )$

$v.w$ and $u.w=0$

$\beta$ is in fact angle between vectors: $-u+w$ and $-v+w$, so $\beta = arccos( { (-u+w).(-v+w) \over |-u+w||-v+w| } )$.

I have struggle simplifying this expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noted, the vectors you're interested in are $(u-w)$ and $(v-w)$. Note that their dot product simplifies:
$$(u-w)\cdot(v-w)=u\cdot v-w\cdot v-u\cdot w+w\cdot w=u\cdot v+w\cdot w.$$
The lengths $|u-w|$ and $|v-w|$ are both $\sqrt{1+|w|^2}$, so you have
$$\cos\beta=\frac{\cos\alpha+|w|^2}{1+|w|^2}.$$